# Application Replaces Another?

Tags: android, html, css, web-applications

I have created 2 Android applications will HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I already have 1 installed on my phone, but when I try to install the other, it would replace the one I already had on my phone! I have an Android Google Pixel XL. Pls tell me how to fix this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## They are used same package name.

Please change package name on Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Are they named the same thing? I'm no professional in making actual mobile apps but they should require different names or tags.